# Mac - Can you batch rename files if they contain certain criteria?

Tags: macos, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a list of filenames containing country codes, for example:

```
File1_BG.srt
File2_CS.srt
```

I'm looking to rename them based on the country code to:

```
File1_BG.srt becomes Facebook.BG_bg.srt
File1_CS.srt becomes Facebook.CS_bg.srt
```

Comment: So you want to replace every occurrence of `File1_` with `Facebook.` and every occurrence of `.srt` with `_bg.srt`. Correct?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question. Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Cross-posted to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410761/can-you-batch-rename-files-if-they-contain-certain-criteria